# Union of odd and even permutations forms the group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have that $S_n$ is the group of permutations of ${1, ..., n}$ and $A_n$ is the alternating group.
If we take an element $γ∈S_n$ with a signature of -1, i.e. it is an odd permutation, and have shown already that $A_n ∩ γA_n = ∅$, how do I go about proving the following statement:

$S_n = A_n ∪ γA_n $

using the hint that for all  $σ ∈ S_n, σ = γγ ^{-1} σ$

Comment: If you have already shown that $A_n\cap \gamma A_n=\emptyset$, then a counting argument shows that the union is $S_n$.

Comment: Can you expand on that I don't understand, I haven't yet shown the cardinality of $A_n$ or $γA_n$, thats part of the following question, so I dont think it is meant to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma\in S_n$. We want to show that $\sigma\in A_n\cup \gamma A_n$.

If $\sigma\in A_n$, we are done.
Suppose $\sigma\notin A_n$, which means that $\sigma$ is odd. Note that $\sigma=\gamma(\gamma^{-1}\sigma)$. Since $\sigma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ are both odd, $\gamma^{-1}\sigma$ must be even. So $\gamma^{-1}\sigma\in A_n$ and therefore $\sigma=\gamma(\gamma^{-1}\sigma)\in \gamma A_n$.
Hence $S_n\subseteq A_n\cup \gamma A_n$.

Since the reverse inclusion is obvious, we conclude that $S_n= A_n\cup \gamma A_n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the multiplicative group $\{-1,1\}$ and show the map
\begin{align}\:\text{sgn}:S_n&\longrightarrow \{-1,1\}\\
\sigma&\longmapsto \text{sgn}(\sigma)
\end{align}
is a group homomorphism.